# Using PHP and MySQLi Query correctly when working out dates

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to PHP / MySQLi and having a little problem and wondering if someone can see what i am doing wrong.

I have 2 fields in question, invoice_date and invoice_due_date which are formatted within the database like "15/03/2017 and 12/04/2017"

What i am trying to do is check invoice_due_date in the query and if date is less than current date to return those items but cannot seem to crack it... here are the few queries i have tried.

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(`total`) as `total` FROM invoices WHERE invoice_due_date < DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%d/%m/%Y') AND invoice_type = 'invoice' AND status = 'open'";
$query = "SELECT SUM(`total`) as `total` FROM invoices WHERE invoice_due_date < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d/%m/%Y') AND status = 'open'";
```

Was assuming would need to convert NOW() to format it needs to compare from to work correctly but clearly im missing something haha

```
DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: If your date is stored as a string and not a date then you need to convert *that* to a date. Not the opposite (converting a date to a string).

Comment: They are set as Varchar if that is what you mean...

Comment: Wrong way of doing things i know, maybe should change it to use date in database

Comment: Changed to DATE in Table and think working as showing something lol thanks mate

Comment: It is better to retrieve the value of the date in the format it is saved in and then convert it to a date value in two steps. These are `$inv_date_uf = date_create($fetched_date);`. Then in the next line `$inv_date = date_format($inv_date_uf, "Y-m-d");`. Now you can use this date in `date_diff` and/or comparisons as well.

Comment: Yea i have made changes in table, and in code and created a few functions to converted dates etc... think got it all working now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your dates to be ISO-8601 dates, `YYYY-MM-DD` in a `DATE` column. You *cannot* compare values like this. It's total nonsense because the fields are not in the right order.

Look at how these sort:

```
2011-02-01
2012-01-01
2015-01-02
```

Versus this which may as well be random even though "ordered":

```
01/01/2012
01/02/2011
02/01/2015
```

Keep your data in the most neutral format possible and apply any necessary date formatting in your display logic.